# Get right edges of pandas interval Categories efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, categorical-data

How can one get pandas interval Categories right edges efficiently? In the example below, how can one create `z` efficiently?

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
bins = pd.interval_range(start=0, end=4, freq=1, closed='left')
x = pd.Series(np.linspace(0.0,3.8,num=20))
y = pd.cut(x, bins)

# How can one create z efficiently?
z = pd.Series(y.iat[n].right for n in range(len(y)))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a performant approach, you can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
np.digitize(x, range(0,4))
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

For a `pd.Series`:

```
pd.Series(np.digitize(x, range(0,4)), index=x.index)

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    3
...
```

---

Timings on a larger dataframe -

```
bins = pd.interval_range(start=0, end=400, freq=1, closed='left')
x = pd.Series(np.linspace(0.0,380,num=20_000))

%timeit pd.Series(np.digitize(x, range(0,400)))
# 567 µs ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

def op(x):
    y = pd.cut(x, bins)
    z = pd.Series(y.iat[n].right for n in range(len(y)))

%timeit op(x)
# 682 ms ± 49.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Where both give the same:

```
np.allclose(op(x), pd.Series(np.digitize(x, range(0,400))))
# True
```

So for a much larger dataframe of 20000 rows we get a **`1200x`** speedup

Comment: This is not efficient. My real data has about hundred billion rows. It has to be a vectorized operation, which does not involve a python level loop.

Comment: Then pandas does not sound like the best way to go for you @S.V maybe numpy would be better here

Comment: numpy way to get the right edges is perfectly fine with me :-)

Comment: I have reversed your edit to the question: one side of `IntervalIndex` can be efficiently received using `left` and `right` methods, but that is not was the task here is.

Comment: Yes, it helped! Thank you very much for your help! I was checking if I could apply it to my situation: the final solution is `bins2 = np.concatenate((bins.left, [bins[-1].right])); z2 = pd.Series(bins2[np.digitize(x, bins2, right=False)], index=x.index); (z==z2).all() # the last command is to check the correctness`